# Why is there such a difference in between my scene and game?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-shader-graph

Here I have 2 screenshots of my problem:
[image: Scene view]
[image: Game view]

By the way my water shader works with `Screen position` and `Scene Depth`.
I can include them here if needed.

Here is my [shader(GoogleDrive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZXmRVd21GT3-BIocH6lgOf-YDpgzK-f/view?usp=sharing)

***Added***

Now it looks like that when I move window "game" to the side:
[image]

***Added***

Here's graph's screenshoots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

P.S. I think it's something in unity's settings but not in shaders(not sure).

Comment: If you'd like help debugging your shader, showing us your shader graph would be step 1.

Comment: @DMGregory added

Comment: Please upload the file here, either copy/paste the text form, or an image. Google drive content tends to get removed, making questions irrelevant.

Comment: I was going to include the contents of your code file directly in your question as part of my edits, but when I checked the contents, it was over 600 lines, which seems somewhat excessive. Please consider making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The thing is I made it in shader graph and idk what I can remove, and what - can't

Comment: A screenshot of the graph is customary. [See past examples on this site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185906/39518)